# Storing pointers to const objects in boost::ptr_unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost-ptr-container

I can't seem to make `boost::ptr_unordered_map<uint32_t, const Foo>` work - the underlying implementation looks like it's casting things to a `void*`.

Do I just have to bite the bullet and make my methods that wrap access to this do a `const_cast<Foo*>` when inserting items, or is there something I'm missing here? Is there any way to store pointers to const objects (`const Foo*`)?

Comment: Does boost::ptr_map work with const object pointers?

Comment: Martin: No, it seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Looking at https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3832 it seems they tried to fix ptr_list in boost 1.43. Couldn't find anything about ptr_map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this isn't possible.

A workaround is to wrap access to `ptr_unordered_map`. The insert method should take a const auto_ptr and then do a `const_cast<Foo*>` to insert it.

If you hand back the auto_type to client code when removing elements, you'll need to unpack the pointer from that and transfer it into a const auto_ptr or similar to make ownership transfer explicit without leaking non-const references.

This is sufficient for my use case, as I don't need to expose any iterator behaviour - it's pure single-element insert/release/look-ups.